# What is the purpose of "typeAndWait" command in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-ide

I am just thinking about command `typeAndWait` in **Selenium**, because I cant figure out any real purpose of it.

In what situation you type in some input and then the page immedeately starts reloading? I can imagine AJAX, but in this case the page doesn't reload - which is the reason, you have to use `waitForXY` commands instead of `xyAndWait` when testing AJAX...

But it was a long day today, maybe I am just dull now and the answer is quite obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google search while you type is the only situation I can think of where that would happen, except your right that the page wouldn't actually load, but there are some weird cases out there that I'm sure I haven't thought of.